# Directly compute element in recursion using bitwise XOR operator

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, fractals

Let's have a matrix **M X N**  matrix ***A[i][j]*** given partially as :(starting with row=0 column =0):

1) for all **1<=i<=N** A[0][i]=0

2) for all **0<=j<=M** A[j][0]=1

The matrix constructs A[i][j] further as:

for all **1<=i<=N** and **1<=j<=M**, A[i][j]=A[i-1][j]^A[i][j-1], where ^ denotes the bitwise XOR operation.

If I want to get some value A[i][j], how can I get that directly (without actually calculating A[i][j] for all 1...j-1 and 1...i-1)? Is there a pattern? Given **M** and **N** are too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's plot out the first 16 rows and columns of the matrix A:

```
1000000000000000
1111111111111111
1010101010101010
1100110011001100
1000100010001000
1111000011110000
1010000010100000
1100000011000000
1000000010000000
1111111100000000
1010101000000000
1100110000000000
1000100000000000
1111000000000000
1010000000000000
1100000000000000
```

The answer to your question "is there a pattern" is pretty clearly "Yes!" The 8x8 submatrix in the top left is copied directly below itself and also directly to the right, except the copy to the right has a 0 in its top-left corner instead of a 1. The bottom-right 8x8 submatrix is all 0's, except it has a 1 in the top-left corner. This exact same pattern emerges if we study just the first 8 rows and columns:

```
10000000
11111111
10101010
11001100
10001000
11110000
10100000
11000000
```

The top-left 4x4 submatrix is copied directly below itself and also directly to the right, except the copy to the right has a 0 in its top-left corner instead of a 1. The bottom-right 4x4 submatrix is all 0's, except it has a 1 in the top-left corner.

This recursive self-similarity makes the matrix A a fractal, quite similar to the [Sierpinski triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle).

The recursive self-similarity also enables us to easily compute A[i][j] using the binary representations of i and j. Let B be the highest-order bit set in the binary representation of either i or j. Then the following procedure will return the correct value of A[i][j]:

- for b = B to 0:

  - if j=0 when limited to bits 0 through b, then return 1 (we are on the first column, which is all 1's)
  - else if i=0 when limited to bits 0 through b, then return 0 (we are on the first row)
  - else if i and j both have a 1 stored in bit b, then return 0 unless all remaining bits in each are 0, in which case return 1
  - else continue (we recurse to a smaller sub-matrix)

This algorithm runs in O(log(max(i,j))) runtime, which is much faster than the O(ij) runtime of the naive approach.

Let's see this algorithm in action with a few examples:

- A[9][9] = 0 from the matrix above. In binary representation, i = 1001 and j = 1001. Both have a 1 in the most significant bit and have some bits set after that one, so by the rules above we return 0.
- A[9][3] = 1 from the matrix above. In binary representation, i = 1001 and j = 0011. In the leftmost (most significant bit), i has a 1 and j has a 0. Therefore we proceed to the next bit (recurse), where both have a 0. We again proceed to the next bit, where i has a 0 and j has a 1. We therefore proceed to the last bit. Both have a 1 in the bit and all following bits are 0's (this is trivially true since there are no following bits), so we return 1.
- A[9][4] = 1 from the matrix above. In binary representation, i = 1001 and j = 0100. In the leftmost (most significant bit), i has a 1 and j has a 0. Therefore we proceed to the next bit (recurse), where i has a 0 and j has a 1. We again proceed to the next bit, where both have a 0. j has a 0 in this and all following bits, so we return 1.

One interesting implication of this algorithm is that each row k (for k > 0) has a repeating pattern with period 2^B, where B is the most significant bit of the row number's binary representation. For instance, row 3 (binary representation 11) repeats 1100, while row 9 (binary representation 1001) repeats 1111111100000000. This means the full repeating series of row k > 0 can be represented in O(k) storage and can be computed in O(k log k) time by separately computing A[k,j] for j = 0, 1, ..., 2^ceiling(log_2 k)-1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I want to get a whole row if suppose I have computed first few rows so that I can calculate any row from precomputed row in O(log n)? Is this possible? Because I see that any row say X is very similar to the row X-2^(max power of 2).

Comment: @mahendersingh If you want to compute the first n elements of row k, then you need at least O(n) time no matter what approach you select. If you computed each element separately using the approach form my answer, you will be able to compute in O(n log(max(n,k))) runtime, which should still be very fast.

Comment: I appreciate your answer,but I do have many queries ,instead of getting each element of that particular row ,say I need sum or say xor of all elements  of that particular row ,then Can't I do that more efficiently? plz read  full of my previous comment

Comment: @mahendersingh I don't see a way to do it more easily/quickly. Sorry. Again, if you want to compute n elements of a row it is hopeless to do this in O(log(n)) runtime as you ask -- it takes O(n) work just to write the output values. The solution I posted here is not really much slower than O(n).

Comment: @mahendersingh I added a comment about computing the repeating pattern for a given row. I hope this helps address your question.